# VB6: Copy file within network shares

Tags: vb6

I am tring to copy a file in the current folder of the executable to a networkshare.

I used the following code, but if the file exists, it won't replace it. It be nice for it to ask if the user want to replace or not.

```
 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 oFSO.GetFile("c:\file.txt").Copy "\\server\sharename\", True
```

Comment: Noticed that in fact it does replace, just have to wait like 10 seconds more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to build your own logic for checking that the file exists and raise the message box manually based on that. You can use the [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to check if the file exists.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample works for me for copying files.  Your network share may be denying access.

FYI, there is an alternative - use FileCopy like this:

```
FileCopy <source file>, <destination file>
```

It will overwrite the destination without prompting.  If you want to prompt, I can think of two ways:

1. Use [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28VS.85%29.aspx) like Gavin suggests, and ask the user if they want to overwrite.
2. Use functionality built into Windows for this.  It sounds like this might be your best choice.  The [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) API will display a progress dialog with a Cancel button while the file copies.  It will also prompt for overwrite.  The dialogs used are the same as used by Windows Explorer.  Use FO_COPY for wFunc; I don't think you need to set any flags in fFlags but there might be some of interest.  Set pFrom / pTo to your source/destination files/directories, and hwnd to the owner window (or 0 if none).  Everything else in the structure can be NULL / 0 / empty.

Comment: `FileCopy` does not work if source file is open with share read. FSO works just fine.